# Maximizing an expression with multiple constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm asked to write a function `solvelinear[k_,m_]` using `LinearProgramming` that maximizes the expression $$\sum_{i=1}^4\left(i-\frac{k^2}{m}\right)^2x_i$$ subject to constraints

- $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=m$
- $x_1+2x_2+3x_3+4x_4=k^2$
- $x_1+x_3\leq k$
- $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ are integers.

I'm reading the tutorial on `LinearProgramming` but it seems to minimize things? Following the tutorial I came up with this:

```
solvelinear[k_, m_] := 
 LinearProgramming[{(1 - k^2/m)^2, (2 - k^2/m)^2, (3 - k^2/m)^2, (4 - 
      k^2/m)^2}, {{1, 1, 1, 1}}, {{m, 0}}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{k^2, 
    0}}, {{1, 0, 1, 0}}, {{k, -1}}, Integers]
```

It doesn't work and I should maximize things anyway. Is there a way to do this with `LinearProgramming` or should I just use `Maximize`?

Comment: What are the constaints on `k` and `m`?

Comment: The only information given is that they are integers

Comment: But doesn't my choice of k and m give a bound for $x_i$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Just to be sure: by integers you mean also negative integers or only non-negative? Because in the former the constrains allow the sum to be arbitrarily big, while in the latter there's a unique solution.

Comment: @corey979 Yes, only non-negative integers are allowed.

Comment: @corey979 Now `solvelinear[k_, m_] := 
 LinearProgramming[{(1 - k^2/m)^2, (2 - k^2/m)^2, (3 - k^2/m)^2, (4 - 
      k^2/m)^2}, {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 0, 1, 0}}, {{m, 
    0}, {k^2, 0}, {k, -1}}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {Integers, Integers, 
   Integers, Integers}]` seems to work but doesn't give the correct answer for m=26 and k=8

Comment: Maximizing $f$ is the same as minimizing $-f$, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three ways.

### Method 1.

```
Clear[k, m, x, c1, c2, c3, sum, max]
```

Define the constraints:

```
c1 = x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] == m;
c2 = x[1] + 2 x[2] + 3 x[3] + 4 x[4] == k^2;
c3 = x[1] + x[3] <= k;
```

Define the sum to be maximized:

```
sum = Sum[(i - k^2/m)^2 x[i], {i, 1, 4}]
```

Define a function that attempts to maximize the `sum` for given `m, k`:

```
max[k_, m_] := 
 Evaluate @ Maximize[{sum, c1, c2, c3, x[1] >= 0, x[2] >= 0, x[3] >= 0, x[4] >= 0},
    {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]}, Integers]
```

Test:

```
Quiet @ max[6, 10]
```

> {42/5, {x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 1, x[4] -> 8}}

```
Quiet @ max[7, 10]
```

> {-∞, {x[1] -> Indeterminate, x[2] -> Indeterminate, 
>     x[3] -> Indeterminate, x[4] -> Indeterminate}}

`Quiet` is used because in the second case there are no instances that fulfill the conditions, so there's a bunch of warnings.

### Method 2.

```
Clear[k, m, x, c1, c2, c3, sum, con]
```

Put the constraints into `Solve`:

```
con[k_, m_] := 
 Solve[{x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] == m, 
   x[1] + 2 x[2] + 3 x[3] + 4 x[4] == k^2, x[1] + x[3] <= k, 
   x[1] >= 0, x[2] >= 0, x[3] >= 0, x[4] >= 0}, {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]}, Integers]
```

E.g.

```
con[6, 10]
```

> {{x[1] -> 0, x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 4, x[4] -> 6}, {x[1] -> 0, x[2] -> 1, 
>     x[3] -> 2, x[4] -> 7}, {x[1] -> 0, x[2] -> 2, x[3] -> 0, 
>     x[4] -> 8}, {x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 1, x[4] -> 8}}

Define the sum as a function:

```
sum[k_, m_] := Sum[(i - k^2/m)^2 x[i], {i, 1, 4}]
```

and

```
sum[6, 10] /. con[6, 10]
```

> {12/5, 22/5, 32/5, 42/5}

The last number, `42/5`, is the greatest and corresponds to `{x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 1, x[4] -> 8}` - the same as in the previous method.

This can be wrapped into

```
MaximalBy[Transpose@{sum[6, 10] /. con[6, 10], con[6, 10]}, First]
```

> {{42/5, {x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 1, x[4] -> 8}}}

which can be given a name

```
max2[k_, m_] := MaximalBy[Transpose@{sum[k, m] /. con[k, m], con[k, m]}, First]
```

---

Both methods work for `k = 8` and `m = 26`, giving `552/13` for `{x[1] -> 8, x[2] -> 8, x[3] -> 0, x[4] -> 10}`.

### Method 3.

As showed by [J. M. in the comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133577/maximizing-an-expression-with-multiple-constraints/133587?noredirect=1#comment360418_133587), `LinearProgramming` can be employed as as follows:

```
max3[k_, m_] := 
 LinearProgramming[-Table[(m i - k^2)^2, {i, 4}], {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 
    2, 3, 4}, {1, 0, 1, 0}}, {{m, 0}, {k^2, 0}, {k, -1}}, 
  Table[0, {4}], Integers]
```

with

```
max3[8, 26]
```

> {8, 8, 0, 10}

with a warning:

> LinearProgramming::lpip: Warning: integer linear programming will use a machine-precision approximation of the inputs.

Comment: `LinearProgramming[-Table[(m i - k^2)^2, {i, 4}], {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 0, 1, 0}}, {{m, 0}, {k^2, 0}, {k, -1}}, Table[0, {4}], Integers]` works fine.